# how to use JSR-303 annotations to validate PropertySources

Tags: java, spring, validation, bean-validation

I'm interested in using JSR-303 (Bean Validation) annotations such as `@NonNull` to validate Spring `PropertySources`, specifically configuration files.

I'm wondering if Spring has support for this out-of-the-box, and if not, how can I write such a framework?  Should I validate `PropertySource` or `PropertySources`?

Ideally, this framework would not depend on Spring so it works for folks using other DI frameworks.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where and when do you want to validate these classes? You can always bootstrap your own Validator instance in case you want to build some custom integration. The question is how you want to integrate with Spring. I don't know PropertySource or PropertySources so it is hard to give any more concrete feedback.